# Is it possible to upgrade an old app in AppStore with a totally new one?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have to update an app in AppStore and the company name and app name was changed. The old one is not an iOS native app and the new one it is. Could be possible the publish the new native app as an upgrade of the old one?

Comment: Yes! :) PS: Your name is exactly same as my mother lol

Comment: I'm happy to hear that :). Could you tell me more details or steps I should follow to complete this process?

Comment: As @Fogmeister wrote below. Only bundle id have to be the same. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

The only thing that has to remain the same is the bundle id of the app.

The name, icon and the entire app can change. (If it changes too much it may not be approved by Apple. Ie changing a kids game into a gambling app etc...)

But yeah, you can change the whole thing and start a whole new project. Just use the same bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

> According to the Apple documentation
>
> You can upload the new version of app anytime if you are using the same bundle identifier, no matter how long before you published last version.

**Few pointers to be considered to avoid app rejection:**

1. Add new version of app
2. Update the screenshots( Need to make it compatible with iPhone X too, if you are planning to publish it later April 1, 2018)
3. Update the app icon if you changed in application as well
4. Update the "App Ratings" according to new changes
5. If you have In-App-Purchase in your app, you need to submit the plans along with the submission of new version( according to updated In-App-Purchase guidelines)
6. If you are changing the original concept of app it might be the reason of app rejection. To avoid this explain the changes in "Notes" section